# Сохранение сгенерированного QR кода на сервер

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Использую библиотеку QR Code Styling для генерации QR и мне нужно сохранить их на сервер с уникальным идентификатором. В js не силен, но получилось сделать таким вот образом:

```
    const qrCode = new QRCodeStyling({
        width: 490,
        height: 490,
        type: "canvas",
        data: "https://www.vk.com/",
        image: "./img/gvoice_i.png",
        dotsOptions: {
            color: "#fff",
            type: "rounded"
        },
        
        cornersSquareOptions: {
            type: "extra-rounded"
        },
        
        backgroundOptions: {
            color: "transparent"},

        imageOptions: {
            imageSize: 0.5,
            saveAsBlob: true,
            crossOrigin: "anonymous",
            margin: 5
        }
    });

var pngBlob  = qrCode.getRawData('png');
pngBlob.then(value => sendAjax(value));

function sendAjax(pngString) {
    $.ajax('ajax.php',{
        'data': pngString,
        'type': 'POST',
        'processData': false,
        'contentType': 'image/png'
    });
}
```

Таким образом, QR генерируется и обрабатывается в PHP:

```
<?php
$png = file_get_contents('php://input');
$myfile = fopen("white.png", "w");
fwrite($myfile, $png);
?>
```

PNG-файл нормально сохраняется под именем "white", но мне нужно его сохранять под уникальным наименованием.

Каким образом можно передать в обработчик еще и имя файла?

Comment: Передайте через query параметр типа ajax.php?filename=your_unique_filename.png, либо через [FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload).

Answer (score 0):

в ajax запросе написать

```
'data': { photoName: pngString, customName: 'Whatever' }
```

на серверной части

```
$queryString = file_get_contents('php://input');
parse_str($queryString, $data);
```

Теперь в `data` будет ассоциативный массив (в данном случае с ключами `photoName` и `customName`) и можно подставлять данные из любых ключей куда угодно

Comment: Если правильно понимаю, то:

<?php
$queryString = file_get_contents('php://input');
parse_str($queryString, $data);
$name = $data['customName'].".png";
$png = $data['photoName'];
$myfile = fopen($name, "w");
fwrite($myfile, $png);
?>

Но создается пустой файл ".png" тогда на сервере.

Comment: @dragon99 `$_POST["data"]["customName"]`

Comment: @DanilApsadikov также пустой файл создается..

Comment: @dragon99 если убрать строки `'processData': false,` и `'contentType': 'image/png'` которые в данном случае не особо нужны - то сработает... и в целом можно будет просто получать данные из `$_POST`  если угодно